# golang - os.ReadFile takes 1-2ms to read a 2kB file

Tags: go

A function needs to iterate through 50,000+ files and search for a particular string in each.  Each file is about 1-3KB in size. We are using os.ReadFile to read each file but many a time the read itself seems to be taking about 1-2millisecs. That is causing a huge hit on the function's performance.

```
starttime := time.Now()
dat, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
endtime := time.Now()
duration := endtime.Sub(starttime)
fmt.Println("Duration:", duration)//This shows 1-2ms
```

Please let me know what I might be doing wrong, if there is a faster way to open a file and search for a string. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Disk access isn't free. 1-2 ms means at least you're not dealing with rotational media with ~10ms seek times :)

Comment: Why do you think the latency is from the Go program itself? Do you always need to read the entire file? Can you scan the files progressively and reduce the number of reads?

Comment: The file itself is a single JSON object, so we have to read the entire file and then search for a string. I am not aware of any other approach to search for a string recursively and get a list of files that match the string. Please suggest.

Comment: You can try embed directive. [guide](https://zetcode.com/golang/embed/). In my tests it is faster than `os.ReadFile`.

Comment: Thank you, sounds interesting, will try and update you

Answer (score -2):

I'm very new to Go but the primary reason I started looking at it was the concurrency model.

Why not leverage that?

```
func searchInFile(filename, searchString string) bool {
    data, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error reading file %s: %v", filename, err)
        return false
    }

    return strings.Contains(string(data), searchString)
}
```

So this still does the os.ReadFile.  Nothing major here.

But here we should get faster.

```
func searchFiles(files []string, searchString string) map[string]bool {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    results := make(map[string]bool)
    mutex := &sync.Mutex{}

    for _, file := range files {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(filename string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            found := searchInFile(filename, searchString)

            mutex.Lock()
            results[filename] = found
            mutex.Unlock()
        }(file)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    return results
}
```

Now you are loading your files up into a files []string slice.

Then you are loading up a channel and calling a go routine to roll over things concurrently.

And in your main call:

```
func main() {
    // Replace this with the list of your 50k+ file names
    files := []string{"file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"}

    searchString := "needle"
    results := searchFiles(files, searchString)

    for file, found := range results {
        if found {
            fmt.Printf("Found '%s' in %s\n", searchString, file)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this works as I don't have 50K files, but I think it would be faster simply by levering concurrency for you.  But I could be wrong and this is dumb :).

Comment: Thank you very much for the code snippets and the precise comments. I am also new to go and need to read up on the goroutines you stated. Let me try this out and update you on how the performance is.

Comment: A question - will this create 50000 goroutines as we are using Add(1) ? If that is the case, will that cause the function to run slower in having to spin up so many concurrent routines ?

Comment: I handled the problem differently - did a grep using exec, got the files list and used that in rest of function. Much faster in search than opening each file and searching for a string